# SQL to XML - delimited string to separate tage

Tags: sql, xml

I'm trying to output DB table as XML with SQL FOR XML.
Column A contains a comma separated string "value1, value2". I would like to output this string as two rows, where ns1 is a defined namespace.

```
<ns1:root>
<ns1:tag>value1</ns1:tag>
<ns1:tag>value2</ns1:tag>
</ns1:root>
```

What would be the correct SQL syntax?

Thanks for help

Comment: Do you have a query written to split the data into the format you want to export into XML?

Comment: Please tag with the actual RDBMS (product and version) and please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)